# cannot read value of undefined? a few issues

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a lot of the same error. i beleive it is in my loop. I have researcedh the web wit h no answare that would help. The issues i am getting

1) my errors are
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL pirate4.html:1
  11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

2) when the page loads i do not get the buttons for places.

When the buttons are pushed i should get the corresponding talk for each phrase in pirate talk.

first time on stack. any help would be awesome. Thanks

Edit ** here is the code
jsfiddle.net/DseAk/1/

Comment: Could you post some relevant code? Would help a lot.

Comment: ya hit the ask button to quick. http://jsfiddle.net/DseAk/1/

Comment: I could not get them on Jfiddle. But i have them in chrome. Sorry new to jsfiddle so dont know if it is me or the program..

Comment: Tried editing this - Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code - crazy rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with how you are accessing the element. You have an id, use it.

```
outstring +=("<input type=\"button\" value=\"" + phrases[i][j] + "\" onClick='document.getElementById(\"output\").value += \"" + phrases[i][j+1] + " \";'>\n");
```

Comment: is how i access my elements the reason for why i cant get my places buttons to be displayed?